# Help with Finding Probability of Finding Same colored balls

Tags: probability

I have a bag that contains 6 blue, 3 red and 1 yellow balls and I pick 3 balls at random. What is the probability that my 3 chosen balls contains only blue and red color? I tried to solve this using the combinations intuition, but I get 35% as result and the correct answer is 72%. I'm not sure how. Assuming that as soon as I pick, I put the balls back into the bag, how do I even approach this problem? I know that I should be using permutations and combinations, but I lack the intuition behind this. Could someone please explain me this?

Comment: There are $\binom 93$ ways to pick three from the blue red balls.  There are $\binom {10}3$ ways to do it with no restrictions.  The ratio is $\frac {84}{120}=\frac 7{10}$.  I don't see how you get $.35$ , That's clearly far too low.  Why should there be a $65\%$ chance of getting the yellow?  Nor is $72\%$ correct, but that's close.

Comment: Can you write that with the combinators formula that I can use to understrand the intuition behind problems like these?

Comment: I don't know what formulas you prefer.  I wrote this using a standard method for denoting the number of combinations...  As a quick variant, the probability of drawing th eyellow is clearly $\frac 3{10}$ so we subtract from $1$ to get $\frac 7{10}$ as before.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain where the $35\%$ comes from.  And the $72\%$ for that matter (as I say, that's closer, but it's still wrong).

Comment: As another variant, suppose you are drawing sequentially.  The probability that the first ball is non-yellow is $\frac 9{10}$.  Given that, the probability that the second is also non-yellow is $\frac 89$, and given both of those the probability for the third is $\frac 78$ making the total probability $\frac 9{10}\times \frac 89\times \frac 7{8}=\frac 7{10}$ as before.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start we have to be clear on how the ball selection work.

### No Reinsertion

As is written I think there is no reinsertion, so our event $A = \{\text{picking 3 balls only blue and red}\}$ could be written as the disjoint union of
$$\{\text{picking 3 B}\}\cup\{\text{picking 3 R}\}\cup\{\text{picking 2 B,1 R}\}\cup\{ \text{picking 1 B, 2R}\} = A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4$$
How do we evaluate this
$$P(A_1) = \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{\text{from 6 possible choices we pick 3}}{\text{from 10 possible choices we pick 3}}$$
I will not explain the remaining formulas and the conclusion is
$$P(A) = \frac{\binom{6}{3}+\binom{3}{3}+\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{1} + \binom{6}{1}\cdot\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{7}{10}$$
And I don't know how you get $35\%$.

### Reinsertion

In this case at every pick the ball get reinserted in the bag so at each pick we have $9/10$ chance of not picking a yellow ball then
$$P(A) = \frac{9^3}{10^3} = 0,729 \approx 73\%$$

---

The fact that $A$ could be written as disjoint union is independent of the method of picking balls.

Comment: I'm not sure if the first 2 cases are correct. I mean the ask is blue and red, so out of the 3 picked balls you should have a mix of blue and red and not just all blue and all red.

Comment: @joesan Then you should remove the first two and in this case you got $P(A) = \frac{21}{40} = 52.5\%$, still not $72\%$ nor $35\%$.